# MSTest Asserts fail with null reference

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, .net-framework-version

Trying to create a simple test method for a .NET 4.7 Framework project.  All of the examples are for Core or older versions of the MSTest framework.

I can get the test to pass with a simple check for the returned object.  If I try anything more complex, like verify the number of records returned, the tests fail as contentResult is always coming up as null.

I indicated which Asserts are failing.

```
using Locations.Api.Controllers;
using Locations.Api.Domain.Models;
using Locations.Api.Domain.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Results;

namespace Locations.Api.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestLocationsController
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetAllLocations_ShouldReturnAllLocations()
        {
            // Arrange
            List<Location> testLocations = GetTestLocations();

            Mock<ILocationsService> locationsServiceMock = new Mock<ILocationsService>();
            locationsServiceMock.Setup(location => location.GetAllLocations())
                        .Returns(testLocations);

            LocationsController controller = new LocationsController(locationsServiceMock.Object);

            // Act
            IHttpActionResult locations = controller.GetAllLocations();

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(locations, "locations is null");
            var contentResult = locations as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Location>;

            // THESE ALL FAIL
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(locations, typeof(List<Location>), "Wrong Model");      // ERROR: type:<System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Locations.Api.Domain.Models.Location]>. Actual type:<System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Locations.Api.Domain.Models.Location]]>.

            Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content, "contentResult is null");           // ERROR: System.NullReferenceException
            Assert.AreEqual(1, contentResult.Content.Id);                               // ERROR:  System.NullReferenceException
            Assert.AreEqual(2, locations.Count(), "Got wrong number of locations");     //  ERROR:  'IHttpActionResult' does not contain a definition for 'Count'
        }


        private static List<Location> GetTestLocations()
        {
            return new List<Location> {
                    new Location { Id = 1, Name = "Albuquerque", Category = "Terminal", Street = "301 Airport Road NW", City = "Albuquerque", State = "NM", ZipCode = "87121", Latitude = 35.0822720000M, Longitude = -106.7169960000M, NearestMajorCity = "Albuquerque", Phone1 = "(505) 344-1619", Phone2 = null, Avaya = null, GateCode = "1234", SpecificEntranceDirections = "Enter via front gate", SwiftCharitiesAmbassador = "Homer Simpson", Extras = "stuff" },
                    new Location { Id = 2, Name = "Columbus", Category = "Terminal", Street = "4141 Parkwest Drive", City = "Columbus", State = "OH", ZipCode = "43228", Latitude = 39.9668110000M, Longitude = -83.1153610000M, NearestMajorCity = "Cincinnati", Phone1 = "(614) 274-5204", Phone2 = null, Avaya = null, GateCode = "5678", SpecificEntranceDirections = "Enter on west side", SwiftCharitiesAmbassador = "Marge Simpson", Extras = "none" }
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line `Assert.IsInstanceOfType(locations, typeof(List<Location>), "Wrong Model");`, run your tests in debug mode (CTRL+R, CTRL+T), inspect `locations` and `contentResult` in the debugger. It sounds like your casts are failing.

Comment: @vzwick locations is populated as expected.  contentResult is always null, no matter what I try.  I am using the examples from Microsoft Docs:  var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Product>;

Comment: The debugger should be showing you type information in the rightmost column - what type does it say `locations` is?

Comment: locations is not a `List<Locations>` it's an IHttpActionResult.

Comment: At a glance, given the method name and the use of `List<Locations>` used later, `var contentResult = locations as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Location>;` should likely be `var contentResult = locations as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Location>>;`

Answer (score 3):

Your first error on the first failing assertion shows why this isn't working:
locations is of type `OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Location>>`, not `OkNegotiatedContentResult<Location>`.

Since you're using the safe cast, `as`, and the type of location is not `OkNegotiatedContentResult<Location>`, the result of the cast will always be null.

You could adjust the code as follows:

```
var contentResult = locations as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Location>>;

Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult, "contentResult should not be null.");
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(contentResult.Content, typeof(List<Location>), "Wrong Model");      
Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content, "contentResult.Content is null");           
Assert.AreEqual(1, contentResult.Content[0].Id);                               
Assert.AreEqual(2, contentResult.Content.Count, "Got wrong number of locations");
```

Comment: Close, with a couple minor changes, also remove () from Count.  Assert.IsInstanceOfType(contentResult, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Location>>), "Wrong Model");

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko I've adjusted my answer a bit to reflect this, I went a slightly different way with the IsInstanceOfType check, since I think it more closely matches what you're confirming. You may want to assert that contentResult is not null right after you cast.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko As an unrelated aside, you may want to look into the `FluentAssertions` library for handling your asserts.